Choosing an evaluation model for LLM for Question and Answering
I was learning the basic of LLM evaluation and the framework introduced in one of the short courses in Deep Learning AI was to generate samples of question and answer which act as the ground truth. Later, the prediction returned from the model that need to be evaluated will be compared with the ground truth.
According to what have been done in the course, the model that will be evaluated was also used for generating the ground truth. Is this a proper way of doing it? Wouldn't this will be causing the result of evaluation to be biased as we are using the same model to generate the correct answer?
How is this evaluation framework valuable? Are we using some SOTA model to generate ground truth for evaluating other smaller-scale LLM?
